# Woocommerce - Show products on sale on wordpress homepage - wp_query

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I made custom wp_query to show my sale products on woocommerce homepage but I can't show correct sale products on homepage. I can see only 3 products (on of them is on sale, 2 others are not). Shordcode shows correct sale products, but my query going crazy. I can't use shortcode because I need to create carousel.

Code below:

```
$args = array(
'post_type'      => 'product',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_query'     => array(
'relation' => 'OR',
          array( // Simple products type
                            'key'           => '_sale_price',
                            'value'         => 0,
                            'compare'       => '>',
                            'type'          => 'numeric'
                        ),
                        array( // Variable products type
                            'key'           => '_min_variation_sale_price',
                            'value'         => 0,
                            'compare'       => '>',
                            'type'          => 'numeric'
                        )
                    )
                );

                $saleproducts = new WP_Query( $args );

                if ( $saleproducts->have_posts() ) : 
                while ( $saleproducts->have_posts() ) : $saleproducts->the_post();

                $post_thumbnail_id     = get_post_thumbnail_id();
                $product_thumbnail     = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_thumbnail_id, $size = 'shop-feature');
                $product_thumbnail_alt = get_post_meta( $post_thumbnail_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true );

----MY HTML CODE HERE----

endwhile; endif; 
wp_reset_query();
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have tested your code, it is not working for variation products because `_min_variation_sale_price` is not exists in `postmeta` table. So I have change query to get on sale products. It is as follow:

```
$query_args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'no_found_rows' => 1,
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'meta_query' => WC()->query->get_meta_query(),
    'post__in' => array_merge(array(0), wc_get_product_ids_on_sale())
);
$products = new WP_Query($query_args);

if ($products->have_posts()) :
    while ($products->have_posts()) : $products->the_post();

        $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
        $product_thumbnail = wp_get_attachment_image_src($post_thumbnail_id, $size = 'shop-feature');
        $product_thumbnail_alt = get_post_meta($post_thumbnail_id, '_wp_attachment_image_alt', true);

        echo get_the_title() . ' - ' . get_the_ID() . '<br/>';
//        ----MY HTML CODE HERE----
    endwhile;
endif;
```

Using this code you can get all on sale products. I have refer it from [here](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/get-a-list-of-woocommerce-sale-products/).

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Wow, thank you! It works. Before you repied to my question I made it in this way: `<?php QUERY args here ?><?php global $product; $promo = $product->is_on_sale(); if ( $promo ) { ?>CONTENT<?php } endwhile; endif; wp_reset_query(); wp_reset_postdata(); ?>` And it was working but your solution is much more elegant.

Comment: I am happy to know that this code helps you.